# Ruby MySQL log all statements to stdout/console

Tags: mysql, ruby

How can I log all executed SQL statements to the console/stdout when using Ruby MySQL?

Like the log/development.log output from rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean [Ruby/MySQL](http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/), that provides a debug() function which performs the same function as [mysql_debug()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-debug.html) -- if your client library has been compiled with debugging, you can get [DBUG to trace things](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_Porting#The_DBUG_Package) for you.  This might give what you're after (with a bit of clean-up.)

Another approach would be to [capture the MySQL packets using tcpdump and decode them with maatkit](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/07/01/gathering-queries-from-a-server-with-maatkit-and-tcpdump/).

A third approach would be to [alias Mysql.query and Mysql.real_query with your own functions](http://www.pluitsolutions.com/2006/10/05/overriding-methods-in-ruby/) that do logging.  Something like this (**untested**! trivial example! doesn't handle blocks!):

```
class Mysql
  alias_method :old_query, :query
  def query(sql)
    $stderr.puts "SQL: #{sql}"
    old_query(sql)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses ORMs like ActiveRecord which has it's logger associated to it.
I don't think MySQL gem has a logger...